# I am trying to run a project but I found an error:

Tags: flutter

Caused by:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.appName.Application
```

Comment: make sure you have the same package name usually starting with "com.yourAppName" through out the android project folder.

Comment: set your project sdk path correctly, It should compile

Comment: @basudevnayak no i just change the pacakage name then post here .

Comment: @SadakatHussainFahad no this is not the sdk error. this exception occure when application about to install on device before installing it buid application correctly but when it comes to the installing to the device application got crashed and show this error

Comment: you might be having different class path aka package name through out the project go through one by one and make sure you have the same classpath through out the project

Answer (score 1):

This error usually means your CLASSPATH doesn't include the path where you code resides.

Comment: application crashe and show me this Exception .and also showing installing application on device and stuck at installing